# creating the right array structure

Tags: javascript, loops

a collection is returning 11 items as follows;

```
   ( 1, "Ball", "Result1") 
   ( 2, "Ball", " Result2") 
   ( 3, "Ball", " Result3") 
   ( 4, "Ball", " Result4") 
   ( 5, "Ball", " Result5") 
   ( 6, "Ball", " Result6") 
   ( 7, "Ball", " Result7") 
   ( 8, "Ball", " Result8") 
   ( 9, "Pool", " Pool 1") 
   ( 10, "Pool", " Pool 2") 
   ( 11, "Pool", " Pool 3")
```

I want to store them, group them as four items..  so that my array looks like this

```
var data = [];
                    data.push({
                    myclass: "First4",
                    schedule: [ {
                        id : '1',
                        gameType: 'Ball',

                        result: 'Result11'
                    }, {
                        id: '2',
                        gameType: 'Ball',

                        result: 'Result2'

                    },...........  ]



                });
                                    //second group
                data.push({
                    divClass : "second4",
                    items : [ {
                        id : '5'
                        gameType: 'Ball',
                        result: 'Result5'
                    }, {
                        id : ''
                        gameType: 'Ball',
                        result: 'Result6

                    } ]
                });
```

how can i write a for loop so that i can achieve the same result dynamically instead of writing the push manually

```
for(var i = 0; i < collLength; i++){
// do push 1 with first four  //data.push(class, sheculde first 4 items, result)
// do second push with second four
// do third push with the remaining

  }
```

Comment: Do you honestly want to name your classes "first4", "second4", etc? It would seem simpler to class them by their array index dynamically "group0", "group1", etc where the number comes from the array index.

Comment: ...but for your loop, just change `i++` to `i+=4`, and then access the items at `i`, `i+1`, `i+2`, `i+3` in the loop.

Comment: i was just trying to make my question clear... What i need to do is, when i receive x number of items, in this case 11, i want to have x number of groups (in this case 3) where each group holds maximum of 4 of the items. I just couldn't write the right for loop to do it dynamically...

Comment: Yeah, just make the loop increment by 4, and access the items at the current index and the next three indexes. Just adjust the `.push()` however you want it, but it looks like you've got a handle on that part.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. They all are working, but is there a away to handle this without using "slice"?

Comment: Yes, you'd take the code below, and instead of `collection.slice(...).map(...)`, you'd do `items: [{id:item[i][0], gameType[i][1], result:[i][2]}, {id:item[i+1][0], gameType[i+1][1], result:[i+1][2]}, {id:item[i+2][0], gameType[i+2][1], result:[i+2][2]}, {id:item[i+3][0], gameType[i+3][1], result:[i+3][2]}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = [];

for(var i = 0; i < collLength; i+=4) {
    data.push({
        divClass: "group" + (i / 4),
        items: collection.slice(i, i + 4).map(function(item) {
            return {id:item[0], gameType:item[1], result:item[2]};
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var indata = [...]; // this is filled with your list of objects.
var outdata = [ ];

var n = indata.length;

for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 4)
{
    outdata.push({
        class: 'group' + outdata.length, 
        items: indata.slice(i, i + 4)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var indata = [...]; // this is filled with your list of objects.
var outdata = [ ];

function mapper(element, i)
{
     var j = Math.floor(i / 4);

     if (outdata[j] == undefined)
         outdata[j] = { class: 'group' + j, items: [ ] };

     outdata[j].items.push(element);
}

indata.map(mapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `.reduce()`.

```
var data = collection.reduce(function(arr, obj, i) {
    return i % 4 ? arr : 
                   arr.concat({
                      divClass: "group" + (i / 4),
                      items: collection.slice(i, i + 4).map(function(item) {
                          return {id:item[0], gameType:item[1], result:item[2]};
                      })
                   });
}, []);
```